# mysql: option '--default-character-set' requires an argument

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Ubuntu 10.10 server
When I run the following command:
mysql

It tells me:
mysql: option '--default-character-set' requires an argument

I've updated the my.cnf file to set the default character set, so I am perplexed.  What am I missing?

---

I've got that line exactly... but something strange is that I have a file at:
    /etc/init/mysql.conf that has

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file="${HOME}"/debian.cnf ping && {
        exec "${HOME}"/debian-start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what does that line in your my.cnf look like, and what version of MySQL are you running? On my installation, it says

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8
```

as specified in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set).

Comment: I updated the question to point out that I think it's the default init script that might be the problem.  Does yours have this line in it?